# MySQL instead of PHP Session

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, session-cookies

What method should I use to keep logged in my users, like google's gmail? (You can stay logged in for almost an unlimited time if you want - stay logged in function - and even if your IP is changed mid-session, gmail still recognize you).

PHP Sessions last until the browser is closed (or 1440 sec), even with the use of `session_set_cookie_parameters()` I don't know if it is a good practice or not. I would prefer using `MySQL` tables instead. One for user login attempts and one for sessions, but I wonder how should I accomplish this.

How can I identify users? The IP is no good, it can change and what if the user uses a proxy? All I want is to use a secure and convenient way.

Let's put aside `Network Eavesdropping` and `Cross-site Scripting`, Im doing my best to counter these attacks. Brute force attacks would be denied with the use of login attempt logging and I use prepared statements to not get sql injected.

My other question is, how can I prevent session hijacking if I want an own login system?

Comment: A session token. But be careful because anyone that Firesheeps the token can use it; using HTTPS will fix this. Take a look at what Twitter or Facebook do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a second specific cookie (ie not the session cookie), named *ALWAYS*

- that cookie is set for a long life (eg a year)
- its value is unique, determined in PHP based on UID and other random (time...) things, made from a hash key (choose your algorithm - md5 is said to be weak), eg "df67ewbhca9fasdi383hd.347234892.HASHFROMUIDSPECIFIC"
- that value is stored in MySQL - user row - when the user logs in
- the following algorithm is followed

  ```
  user_login() {
    if ( not signed in ) {
       if (cookies[ALWAYS] is present AND value is in DB AND not null) {
          log the user from that row , automatically
          create his session
       }
       else {
          regular_login()
       }
    }
  }
  ```
- when the user logs out, delete the cookie ALWAYS, AND set that value to *null* in DB

This way, the users who logged in previously, are (for a year, can be changed) automatically logged in when session expired, from the same browser they initially logged in.

When a user logs out, remove the possibility of a cookie that has been stolen (...) by removing the value from the DB. Thus even though it could be stolen, it cannot be used anymore.